# bundler and rvm: how should i best i package my current installed gems into my folder?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I've recently started using rvm (and bundler) and am in the process of boxing up a project so that everything needed for the project lives in the project folder (and hence in source control), enabling someone checking it out to fire it up straight away with no external dependencies.

So, i'm sitting in my project's root folder, in an rvm with a named gemset, with all the gems i need installed in the current gemset.

Using bundler, can i package all these gems into the project, so that when the project is checked out into a new environment (which will be in an identically named rvm & gemset) i can either

a) install the gems from the gems folder in the project (rather than from rubygems.org for example) or
b) use them directly out of that folder?

rvm and bundler seem to replicate each other's purpose/functionality to some degree and i'm a bit confused...

Grateful for any advice - max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bundle package` command to do that.

You can check the documentation about it : http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-package.1.html